# Can't find JSP files in eclipse select a wizard

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I am trying to build a Dynamic Web project using spring, maven, hibernate and mysql.
When I open elipse wizard there are no option to create a new JSP file
how can i fix this? is there a plug in I should add or something?

Comment: What package of Eclipse did you install? "Eclipse Classic," "Eclipse for Java Developers," etc.

Comment: Android Developer Tools but it has web tools platform and I am working on Java EE perspective.. (does that even answer your question?)

Comment: Maybe it doesn't include all of JST (the portion of Web Tools that contributes the JSP wizard). Did you download from eclipse.org or elsewhere?

Comment: From eclipse.org  I believe

Comment: Which version of Eclipse and Java is this?